# How To Pass Multiple Parameters In A URL To Plug

Tags: elixir

So I'm trying to pass multiple parameters in a URL to plug.  This is the URL I'm using for testing:

```
http://localhost:4000/uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword
```

And this is the code:

```
defmodule Sci do
    @userid "uid"
    @password "pwd"
    import Plug.Conn
    import Plug.Conn.Utils
    use Plug.Router


    plug :match
    plug :dispatch

    get "/:args" do
        %{@userid => usr} = params(args)
        %{@password => pass} = params(args)

        send_resp(conn, 200, "Hello #{usr}. Your password is #{pass}")
    end

    match _ do
        send_resp(conn, 404, "oops")
  end

  def start do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http Sci, [], port: 4000
  end

  def stop do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.shutdown Sci.HTTP
  end
end
```

If I pass just one argument (either uid or pwd) it matches fine.  If I remove the `?` at the front of the query string it fails--throws an exception.

I also tried this:

```
get "/:args" do
  %{@userid => usr, @password => pass} = params(args)
```

Also didn't work.  So two questions:

1.) Is that the right way to pass multiple parameters in a URL?

2.) Is there some trick to get plug to see both parameters?

Any thoughts or insights would be welcome--even a suggestion of a better way to do this.

Elixir v0.15.1 and Plug v0.5.1

EDIT:

Adding a stacktrace per Jose's comment:

```
iex(2)> 07:46:56.499 [error] Error in process <0.232.0> with exit value: {[{reason,{badmatch,#{}}},{mfa,{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler',init,3}},{stacktrace,[{'Elixir.Sci','-do_match/2-fun-0-',2,[{file,"lib/sci.ex"},{line,18}]},{'Eli
xir.Sci',call,2,[{file,"lib/sci.ex"},{line,1}]},{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler'...                                                                                                                                                       


iex(2)> 07:46:56.510 [error] Ranch listener Sci.HTTP had connection process started with :cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at #PID<0.232.0> exit with reason: {[reason: {:badmatch, %{}}, mfa: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, :init, 3}, stacktrace:
 [{Sci, :"-do_match/2-fun-0-", 2, [file: 'lib/sci.ex', line: 18]}, {Sci, :call, 2, [file: 'lib/sci.ex', line: 1]}, {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, :init, 3, [file: 'lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex', line: 7]}, {:cowboy_handler, :handler_
init, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_handler.erl', line: 64]}, {:cowboy_protocol, :execute, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_protocol.erl', line: 435]}], req: [socket: #Port<0.5168>, transport: :ranch_tcp, connection: :keepalive, pid: #PID<0.232.0>, method: "G
ET", version: :"HTTP/1.1", peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 63880}, host: "localhost", host_info: :undefined, port: 4000, path: "/uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPassword", path_info: :undefined, qs: "", qs_vals: :undefined, bindings: [], headers: [{"host
", "localhost:4000"}, {"connection", "keep-alive"}, {"cache-control", "max-age=0"}, {"accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/53
7.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"}, {"accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8"}], p_headers: [{"connection", ["keep-alive"]}], cookies: :undefined, meta: [], body_state: :waitin
g, buffer: "", multipart: :undefined, resp_compress: false, resp_state: :waiting, resp_headers: [], resp_body: "", onresponse: :undefined], opts: {Sci, []}], [{:cowboy_protocol, :execute, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_protocol.erl', line: 435]}]}  

iex(2)> 07:46:56.969 [error] Error in process <0.233.0> with exit value: {[{reason,{badmatch,#{}}},{mfa,{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler',init,3}},{stacktrace,[{'Elixir.Sci','-do_match/2-fun-0-',2,[{file,"lib/sci.ex"},{line,18}]},{'Eli
xir.Sci',call,2,[{file,"lib/sci.ex"},{line,1}]},{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler'...                                                                                                                                                       


iex(2)> 07:46:56.971 [error] Ranch listener Sci.HTTP had connection process started with :cowboy_protocol:start_link/4 at #PID<0.233.0> exit with reason: {[reason: {:badmatch, %{}}, mfa: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, :init, 3}, stacktrace:
 [{Sci, :"-do_match/2-fun-0-", 2, [file: 'lib/sci.ex', line: 18]}, {Sci, :call, 2, [file: 'lib/sci.ex', line: 1]}, {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, :init, 3, [file: 'lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex', line: 7]}, {:cowboy_handler, :handler_
init, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_handler.erl', line: 64]}, {:cowboy_protocol, :execute, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_protocol.erl', line: 435]}], req: [socket: #Port<0.5174>, transport: :ranch_tcp, connection: :keepalive, pid: #PID<0.233.0>, method: "G
ET", version: :"HTTP/1.1", peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 63881}, host: "localhost", host_info: :undefined, port: 4000, path: "/favicon.ico", path_info: :undefined, qs: "", qs_vals: :undefined, bindings: [], headers: [{"host", "localhost:4000"}, {"
connection", "keep-alive"}, {"accept", "*/*"}, {"user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"}, {"accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"}, {"accept-language", "e
n-US,en;q=0.8"}], p_headers: [{"connection", ["keep-alive"]}], cookies: :undefined, meta: [], body_state: :waiting, buffer: "", multipart: :undefined, resp_compress: false, resp_state: :waiting, resp_headers: [], resp_body: "", onresponse: 
:undefined], opts: {Sci, []}], [{:cowboy_protocol, :execute, 4, [file: 'src/cowboy_protocol.erl', line: 435]}]}
```

EDIT 2: 
I had jotted down the wrong URL above; that's now corrected.  Also to add to the question, if I make the URL this: `http://localhost:4000/?uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword`, the code jumps down to the `match _ do` clause

Comment: What failure are you getting? Can you please post the stacktrace? And you definitely need to call fetch_params before.

Comment: I've added the stacktrace.  I hesitated to add it before because I couldn't quite figure out how to format it.

Comment: Ah, I see what is wrong. `:args` is not going to contain the query string. It is going to contain just the path. If you want to access the query string parameters, you need to do exactly as sasa proposed. Which is basically call `fetch_params(conn)` and access it as `conn.params`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL structure you want to use is not really well-formed.
And therefore your issue is framework-agnostic, because almost all frameworks/libraries will have a problem to parse the URL in your intended way.

`/uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword` is treated as a path without any query parameters.

```
PATH: /uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword
QUERY STRING: (empty/unset)
QUERY PARAMS: [ ]
```

I guess you really want to have something like `/?uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword`.

```
PATH: /
QUERY STRING: uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword
QUERY PARAMS: [ uid: "ToddFlanders", pwd: "MyTestPword" ]
```

Furthermore `Plug.Conn.Utils.params/1` is intended to parse header parameters. Use `Plug.Conn.Query.decode/1` for query parameters instead.

So, in your example I would suggest to adjust the application code as following:

```rb
defmodule Sci do
  import Plug.Conn
  use Plug.Router

  @userid   "uid"
  @password "pwd"

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/" do
    conn = fetch_params(conn) # populates conn.params
    %{ @userid => usr, @password => pass } = conn.params
    send_resp(conn, 200, "Hello #{usr}. Your password is #{pass}")
  end

  match _ do
    send_resp(conn, 404, "oops")
  end

  def start do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http Sci, [], port: 4000
  end

  def stop do
    Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.shutdown Sci.HTTP
  end
end
```

And then you can successfully try `http://localhost:4000/?uid=ToddFlanders&pwd=MyTestPword`.

(Also it should not hit the `match(_)` function, because `/` should always match if you do the request to this path properly.

Comment: Ok, I have to admit the difference between header parameters and query parameters wasn't clear to me but after having read your response (among those others) I see that I was mixing up the two ideas.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not versatile with Plug, but for a demo code, I used [fetch_params/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/plug/Plug.Conn.html#fetch_params/1) and then `conn.params["foo"]`, `conn.params["bar"]` and so on, and this definitely worked.

**Update**: since Plug 0.12.0, [fetch_query_params/2](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#fetch_query_params/2) should be used

Comment: It's a good suggestion but it still doesn't seem to be working. Could you point me to your demo code?

Comment: I don't have it online, but here's a sketch: https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/99cc0526f5b4dd903e21

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it either Sasa.  I'd paste the stacktrace up here but I get the feeling that I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Here's the working demo: https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/1917609ecd6127f736e6. I've just tried with Elixir 0.15.0 and Plug 0.6. Include it in your mix project, make sure you call Web.start_server from somewhere, and try it out. I can't see your code, so a blind guess - are you threading connection while handling a request? This is crucial, because every operation (such as fetch_params) returns a modified conn struct. If you run fetch_params, but then look into the previous version of conn struct, you won't find those params there. You have to use the result of fetch_params (new conn).

Comment: I'll take a look at the working demo when I get a chance; thanks for your assistance Sasa!

Comment: The docs link in this answer now leads to a 404 and I'm getting `(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Plug.Conn.fetch_params/1`. Was this function replaced by something else? (P.S. I'm enjoying your book!)

Comment: `fetch_query_params` looks like the actual function name.

Comment: @CoderDennis Yes, this happened at 0.12.0, see https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/263f5ed01889611df8ecc25260e02091d095e9f3/CHANGELOG.md#v0120. I'll update the answer, thanks for pointing this out. (P.S. glad you like the book :-) )

Answer (score 3):

You should use `fetch_query_params` now.
https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#fetch_query_params/2

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
params = conn.query_params
IO.inspect(params["your_param"])
```

Or you can use pattern matching like this (if you have ONE parameter only or if you want to pass the map exactly as is received):

```
%{"your_parameter"=>your_parameter} = conn.query_params
IO.inspect(your_parameter)
```